# How to create a trigger that fires after an update in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, sql-update, plsqldeveloper

I will like to create a trigger, that when Movie_Qty in the Fin_Movie table is updated to a 0, the message "(Movie Title) is no longer available"

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER movie_trg
AFTER UPDATE OF movie_qty
ON fin_movie
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (new.movie_qty = 0)
BEGIN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' will no longer be available');
END;
```

It compiles, but I dont know how display the movie_title before in the output.

Thank you

Comment: in Oracle database you should be `on` `serveroutput` with following statement - `set serveroutput on`. Then only message from `Dbms_output.put_line` will be displayed to the display screen.

Comment: The Dbms_output.put_line displays ' will no longer be available' currently,  I would like to add the movie_title to that statement.

So in other words, I would like to display the Movie_Title of the the Movie_Qty that has been updated to 0, and is ' will no longer be available'

Comment: simply you can write `New.movie_name` appending with your display message .. like `Dbms_output.put_line('will no longer be available '||New.movie_name);` I think this should solve your problem ..

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE   
TRIGGER SAL_TRG1 AFTER UPDATE ON EMPC 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
     if (:new.salary =0) then
          raise_application_error (-20110,'invalid length');
     end if;
end;
```